# Piping output using subprocess.Popen and subprocess.PIPE

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pipe, subprocess, popen

I'm relatively new at python and would really appreciate help regarding its subprocess module.
Using Popen can someone tell me how to pipe the output of process1 (which is the ls command) to process2(which is gedit hello.txt) The code which I use doesn't throw any error, but doesn't pipe the output of ls either. hello.txt is initially blank, and remains blank after the script is executed.

```
from subprocess import *
a = Popen(['ls'],stdout = PIPE,shell=True)
b = Popen("gedit hello.txt",stdin = a.stdout,shell=True)
```

If possible, I would really appreciate it if one of you could explain the general method of how to pipe data. Thanking you in advance.

PS: I've used shell=True because I had read on one of the forums that PIPE needs shell=True to work.

Comment: You don't need `shell=True` for pipes to work.

Comment: `gedit` doesn't accept anything on standard input. What do you want to accomplish here?

Comment: There is a better duplicate but I could not quickly find it. Anyway, the answer which summarizes the relevant part of the `subprocess` documentation should be all you need.

Comment: I have tried to adapt those methods only replacing sed with gedit, but they haven't worked. That is why i had asked the question.

Comment: Sorry I did not realize that gedit does not accept anything on standard input